# Type mismatches with Scala Try

Tags: scala

Below, I am trying to extract a Tweet JSON field    `retweeted_status`. I check if the JSON contains the field and then use `Try` to extract it. I would like to assign the extracted value on success to the var  `retweet_count` and on failure, assign `retweet_count` as 0. But when I try this  `case Success(result)=> retweet_count = result` I get a mismatch error stating that BigInt cannot match with Unit.

Printing out the class of `retweeted_favorite_count2` I get `scala.runtime.BoxedUnit`. What is the work around this?

```
var retweet_count: BigInt= 0
if (value.has("retweeted_status")){
  val retweeted_favorite_count0 = value\"retweeted_status"\"favorite_count"
  val retweeted_favorite_count1 = Try(retweet_count=retweeted_favorite_count0.extract[BigInt])
  val retweeted_favorite_count2 = retweeted_favorite_count1 match {
                case Success(result)=> result
                case Failure(exception)=> 0
                case _=> 0
              }
  println(" retweeted_favorite_count2"+ retweeted_favorite_count2.getClass )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contents of your `Try` is an assignment: `retweet_count=...` Assignments have no meaningful return value so the `result` in `Success(result)` is not an `Int`.

You can get around this by making the assignment after assessing the `Try`.

```
val retweeted_favorite_count2 =
  Try(retweeted_favorite_count0.extract[BigInt]) match {
    case Success(result)=> 
      retweet_count = result
      result
    case Failure(_)=> 0
  }
```